# Cannot read text file into 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I tried to read the text file into 2D array through Python.
The text file is like:

```
7ee0c0d15fe800000f80202278e0c0f1
00007ee0c0d15fc000000f802022c0f1
```

I need the 2D Array format like:

```
[[[7],[e],[e],[0],[c],[0],[d],[1],[5],[f],[e],[8],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[f],[8],[0],[2],[0],[2],[2],[7],[8],[e],[0],[c],[0],[f],[1]],
[[0],[0],[0],[0],[7],[e],[e],[0],[c],[0],[d],[1],[5],[f],[c],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[f],[8],[0],[2],[0],[2],[2],[c],[0],[f],[1]]]
```

The elements are hex numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('filename') as f:
    array2d = [[int(c,16) for c in line.rstrip()] for line in f]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "wanted" output is 3d not 2d - this is how to get a 2d output:

Create file:

```
data = """7ee0c0d15fe800000f80202278e0c0f1
00007ee0c0d15fc000000f802022c0f1"""
fn = "someFile.txt"
with open(fn,"w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Read file:

```
fn = "someFile.txt"
k = []
with open(fn,"r") as f:
    for line in f:
      k.append(list(line.rstrip("\n"))) # convert each line into list, strip \n

print(k) # these are all strings

# convert to int
d = [ [int('0x'+i,16) for i in x] for x in k]

print(d) # 2d list
```

Output:

```
[['7', 'e', 'e', '0', 'c', '0', 'd', '1', '5', 'f', 'e', '8', 
  '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'f', '8', '0', '2', '0', '2', '2', 
  '7', '8', 'e', '0', 'c', '0', 'f', '1'], 
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '7', 'e', 'e', '0', 'c', '0', 'd', '1', 
  '5', 'f', 'c', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'f', '8', '0', 
  '2', '0', '2', '2', 'c', '0', 'f', '1']]

[[7, 14, 14, 0, 12, 0, 13, 1, 5, 15, 14, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15,
  8, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 7, 8, 14, 0, 12, 0, 15, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 14, 14, 0, 12, 0, 13, 1, 5, 15, 12, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 15, 8, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 12, 0, 15, 1]]
```

To get to your output, simply wrap the integer conversion into a 1 - elem list:

```
# convert to 3d int
d3 = [ [ [int('0x'+i,16)] for i in x] for x in k]
print(d3) # converted to int
```

Output:

```
[[[7], [14], [14], [0], [12], [0], [13], [1], [5], [15], [14], [8], [0], [0],
  [0], [0], [0], [15], [8], [0], [2], [0], [2], [2], [7], [8], [14], [0],
  [12], [0], [15], [1]], 
 [[0], [0], [0], [0], [7], [14], [14], [0], [12], [0], [13], [1], [5], [15], 
  [12], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [15], [8], [0], [2], [0], [2], [2], 
  [12], [0], [15], [1]]]
```

To get be left with "hex-strings" in your output, don't do integer conversion:

```
# convert to 3d int
d3h = [ [ [i] for i in x] for x in k]
print(d3h) # converted to int
```

Output:

```
[[['7'], ['e'], ['e'], ['0'], ['c'], ['0'], ['d'], ['1'], ['5'], ['f'], ['e'], 
  ['8'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['f'], ['8'], ['0'], ['2'], ['0'], 
  ['2'], ['2'], ['7'], ['8'], ['e'], ['0'], ['c'], ['0'], ['f'], ['1']], 
 [['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['7'], ['e'], ['e'], ['0'], ['c'], ['0'], ['d'], 
  ['1'], ['5'], ['f'], ['c'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['0'], ['f'], 
  ['8'], ['0'], ['2'], ['0'], ['2'], ['2'], ['c'], ['0'], ['f'], ['1']]]
```

(or in short:

```
with open(fn,"r") as f:
    k = [ [ [k] for k in i] for i in (list(line.strip()) for line in f)]
print(k)
```

which is the same output)

Answer (score 2):

This is just to have an idea

```
import numpy as np
x,y = np.genfromtxt('data.txt',dtype='str', usecols=(0,1), unpack=True)
x_letter = []
y_letter = []
letter = [x_letter]

for letter in x:
    letters = [letter] 
    x_letter.append(letters)

for letter in y:
    letters = [letter] 
    y_letter.append(letters)

final = [x_letter,y_letter]
print (final)
```